# jQuery $.ajax not passing variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I want to make a 'show more' button with jQuery AJAX. I have a button with a `loaded` attribute like so:

```
<button type="button" class="smbt btn center-block" data-loaded="3">Show More</button>
```

In the javascript file I wrote this:

```
var smbt = $(".smbt");

smbt.click(function() {
    var limit = $(smbt).attr('loaded');
    // alert(loaded + " picture");

    $.ajax({
        url: '../view/profile.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({limit1: limit}),
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Then I try to get the `limit1` variable:

```
$limit = $_POST["limit1"];
```

I read the `$.ajax` documentation and a lot of questions and answers, I tried a lot of way to make it work but it always gives this error:

> Undefined index: limit1

Comment: What you have should work fine. Check the console for errors in your JS code. Also note that inventing your own properties (ie. `loaded`) is invalid HTML. You should use `data-*` attributes to store your own meta data in an element, although that won't affect the AJAX you're using here.

Comment: Try changing `data: ({limit1: limit}),` to `data: {limit1: limit},`

Comment: I tried to use data-loaded and I also tried to change ({limit1: limit}), to data: {limit1: limit} but still get the error :(

Comment: Did you check for errors in the console?

Comment: Yes I checked and it is only shows success.

Comment: Try this: `if (isset($_POST["limit1"])){ $limit = $_POST['limit1']; }`

Comment: It's not works as I wanted because it's just hide the error message if its not get any value. But I need that value to increase the limit to show more and more item from the database as the button is clicked.

Comment: F.Y.I. you should use a `data-loaded` attribute and not `loaded` as adding your own custom attributes is not HTML compliant.

Comment: Yes I already changed it but still get the error. I fix the code here.

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If once someone also had this problem this is how I made it work.

So there is a profile.php which contains and shows the uploaded pictures. I want want to use a button which increase the LIMIT in sql. So the profile.php contains everything. There is a div which contains the pictures wit query result and after it have the load more button. It's looks like this:

```
<div class="row mg-bt-20" id="cont">
                <?php
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "  <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 mg-bt-20'>
                                        <div class='pics' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' data-target='#myModal'>
                                        <img src='" . $row['path'] . "'>
                                        <p class='text-center' style='line-height: 6vh;'>". $row["description"] ."</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<p style='text-align: center; color:#fff; font-size: 20px;'>No posts yet.</p>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

The problem was I try to send the variable to this profile.php but it's not work at all. I tried everything but it's just not working. So I made a new php file called show_more.php which contains only the php query results from the code above:

```
<?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "  <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 mg-bt-20'>
                        <div class='pics' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' data-target='#myModal'>
                        <img src='" . $row['path'] . "'>
                        <p class='text-center' style='line-height: 6vh;'>". $row["description"] ."</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p style='text-align: center; color:#fff; font-size: 20px;'>No posts yet.</p>";
    }
?>
```

So my jQuery code is:

```
    var smbt = $(".smbt");
    var limit = $(smbt).data('loaded');

    smbt.on('click',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        limit += 3;
        console.log(limit);
        // alert(loaded + " picture");

        $.ajax({
            url:"../php/show_more.php",
            data: {limit1: limit},
            success:function(data){
                $("#cont").html(data);
            }
        });
```

This is successfully send the limit1 variable to the show_more.php.

In the show_more.php I just write `$_POST["limit1"]` to get the data.

And the sql query looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images  where user = '$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
```

So here is how it's work:

First of all when the profile.php is loaded the pictures are shows if you have one but its limited to shown only 3 at first. So after you click the load more button it runs the ajax code which increase the limit variable with 3 so we get a new number which is 6 now (I always increase with 3). The ajax code first send the data to the given url which is the show_more.php in this case. I write it in oop so I have a class which handle all the image thing and I have a function in it which show the images so i just pass a variable in it like this `public function showImg($limit){...}`. So here is where the magic happens. It's always change the limit number once I clicked. after when it's happened in ajax code the success part handle the result. The result will the html code which will be added to the image container.

I hope I help with this and I didn't write stupid things(also sorry for my english). It works for me in this form.

And thanks for everybody whose help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var smbt = $(".smbt");

smbt.click(function() {
  var limit = $(smbt).data('loaded');

  $.ajax({
      url: './view/profile.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {limit1: limit},
      success: function(result) {
          console.log("success");
      },
      error: function() {
          alert("error");
      }
  });
});
```

You are using data-* attribute, so to get the value, you use $.data() function: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/